# Algorithm to find the MST with weight defined as the maximum weight edge in the spanning tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I'm working on a problem in which we define the weight of a minimum spanning tree to be weight of the maximum weight of a MST, and I'm trying to find an algorithm that can find such a tree from a connected graph $G$.

My intuition is that the procedure should be no different from those of Kruskal's or Reverse Delete. However, I'm struggling to find a way to formalize the argument. Can you throw me some hints on that? Thanks

Comment: "weight of the maximum weight of a MST" Huh? I think you mean what you have in the title, weight of an edge of maximal weight. If so, please edit the body of your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "reverse delete", but Kruskal should work, since the first thing you do with Kruskal is order the edges by increasing weight, and then add edges in that order.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.